# Programmatically creating configurable products / pricing_value empty

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create configurable product programmatically. I have a problem only with price for each size attribute. pricing_value is allways empty in admin panel. Here is same problem but there is no answer [Creating configurable products programmatically - pricing_value not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525336/creating-configurable-products-programmatically-pricing-value-not-saved) I am using magento community 1.9.1

```
try {
    $configProduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $configProduct->setSku('dp_' . strtotime('now'))
        ->setAttributeSetId(9)
        ->setTypeId('configurable')
        ->setName('Some cool product name')
        ->setCategoryIds(array(3))
        ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
        ->setDescription('Full description here')
        ->setShortDescription('Short description here')
        ->setPrice(39.99)
        ->setWeight(1.0000)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setStatus(1)
        ->setTaxClassId(0)
        ->setMediaGallery (array('images' => array (), 'values' => array ()))
        ->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $mediaAttribute, false, false )
        ->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 999,
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
            'is_salable' => 1
        ))
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));

        $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $configProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(132)); //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
        $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();


        $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

        $configurableProductsData = array();

        $configurableProductsData['10'] = array(
            '0' => array(
                'label' => (string)Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(10)->getName(),
                'attribute_id' => '132', //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
                'value_index' => '3', //value of 'X' index of the attribute 'size'
                'is_percent' => false, //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '21.00' //value for the pricing
            )
        );
        $configurableProductsData['11'] = array(
            '0' => array(
                'label' => (string)Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(11)->getName(),
                'attribute_id' => '132', //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
                'value_index' => '4', //value of 'XL' index of the attribute 'size'
                'is_percent' => false, //fixed/percent price for this option
                'pricing_value' => '21.00' //value for the pricing
            )
        );
        $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
        $configProduct->save();
        $createdProductUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $configProduct->getSku())->getUrlPath();
    echo json_encode(array("createdProductUrl"=>"http://magento.dev/index.php/test/" . $createdProductUrl));
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: maybe need to define base currency ?

Answer (score 0):

i was having this same problem, looked around every where but i found a solution. figured it out from here

[Creating configurable products programmatically - pricing_value not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525336/creating-configurable-products-programmatically-pricing-value-not-saved/28277635#28277635)

you need to add the configurable products data to $configurableAttributesData as shown there. this is the solution i saw everywhere that wasnt working for me until the next step.

change the structure of $configurableProductsData to

$configurableProductsData['11'] = array(

```
            'label' => (string)Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(11)->getName(),
            'attribute_id' => '132', //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
            'value_index' => '4', //value of 'XL' index of the attribute 'size'
            'is_percent' => false, //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '21.00' //value for the pricing

    );
```

remove the second array